# How to add completely custom URLs to Sitemap in module XMLSitemap in Drupal 7

Tags: database, path-aliases, xml-sitemap

I have a website with which has some different URLs that are not inserted in the **url_alias** table not embedded into Drupal content system, but they are generated on-the-fly by custom PHP logic inside a module.

How can I alter the sitemap generated by [XMLSitemap modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) in order to include these generated "artificial" URLs?

For example:

```
www.example.com/products is a content node.
```

When accessing

```
www.example.com/products/category1/subcategory2
```

I see the list of the products under category1 and subcategory 2, but generated on the fly by custom code, from data from other repository different to Drupal's one.

The URL

```
 www.example.com/products/category1/subcategory2
```

is not in the database table: **url_alias** and it does not pertain to a different node to the first one (whithout parameters), either: the screen displays different info based only on the custom module.

I would like to know how to include this URL in a automated way in the xml sitemap.

Comment: You need to implement hook_xmlsitemap_index_links(), and use the xmlsitemap_link_save() function.  The easiest thing to do is to look at the existing implementations for node and menus.  I'll see if I can dig up a generic example for you.

Comment: I have looked the API info, and the problem is that the data model seems to need the node->id or the entity_id, so I would have a problem for not having the "external" products mapped to Drupal nodes. I could use a partial Feeds import, but would be great if I could just insert a link (not the object, but a link string) in the output stream in the last moment. I would thank you the example, but as I say, I cannot see that my data model fits the API requeriments.

Comment: You can map arbitrary data (out of the box, the module support custom links).  The last time I did this was about two three years ago, so I just need to dust off the cobwebs to give you an example.

Comment: Ok, I will appreciate very much.

Comment: Any updates on this?